# Delphi XE2 listview artifacts

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, tlistview

I am using listview in vsreport virtual mode, have two columns and after I populate the list, select one row, and then select some other row there's an artifact left on a previously selected row, see image below. How to fix this?[image]

and this is my code that gets the data from an array

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1Data(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
  Item.Caption := FloatToStr(Item.Index + 1);
  Item.SubItems.Add(FloatToStr(a[Item.Index]));
end;
```

When I hover the mouse, the artifacts dissapear.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide screenshot and code (if it is needed to reproduce)

Comment: OK, I can reproduce now. It will only do it for virtual mode.

Comment: Apparently setting the listview's doublebuffered property to true solves the problem. Not sure what to do with this question now.

Comment: I don't like that solution. I have a very similar list view that does not behave that way. Please leave the question open. The other person who will likely help is Sertac who is a wizard with comctl32 controls.

Comment: OK, I'm getting somewhere. If I make the form derive from my own base form class, the artifacts disappear. I just need to work out what is special about my form.

Comment: Ha! Turns out that my code sets `DoubleBuffered` for list views because that's the only way I've found to stop resize flicker. So I've got nothing more than you managed to work out all by yourself.

Comment: If I were you I would add that as an answer. I'll vote for it. This is a very useful observation. Would be nice to keep it around.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting the listview's DoubleBuffered property to true solves the artifacts problem.