# Delphi Listview leaves selection marks behind

Tags: delphi, listview, selection

under XE2 I have the problem that the standard TListLiew leaves selection marks behind when a row was selected and the mouse moves to a different row. This can be easily reproduced using the following code:

```
unit MainForm;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ComCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
    lvw: TListView;
    procedure lvwData(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  col: TListColumn;
begin
  lvw := TListView.Create(Self);
  lvw.Parent := self;
  lvw.Align := alClient;
  lvw.MultiSelect := true;
  lvw.RowSelect := true;
  lvw.ViewStyle := vsReport;
  lvw.OwnerData := true;

  col := lvw.Columns.Add;
  col.Caption := 'First';
  col.Width := 100;
  col := lvw.Columns.Add;
  col.Caption := 'Second';
  col.Width := 100;

  lvw.OnData := lvwData;
  lvw.Items.Count := 15
end;

procedure TForm1.lvwData(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
  Item.Caption := 'Hallo';
  Item.SubItems.Add('Halli');
end;

end.
```

This yields the following result when I select one or more rows and move the mouse over another row:

[image]

the "dropped" selection marks are cleared when the mouse moves over the previously selected rows.

- Does anybody have an idea how I can prevent this from happening?
- Do I have to customdraw the list items?

Comment: Does it also happen if you put the listview on the form at designtime?

Comment: Yes, it does. That was my first demo, but I wanted to have it all in code, to be able to post it here.

Comment: Sure - just checking

Comment: Thanks Sertac, if I had found that answer with the search it would have saved me some hours already.

Comment: @Lübbe - You're welcome. I couldn't easily locate the question either, even though I knew it existed.

Comment: Is your form and listbox doublebuffered?

Comment: yes, now it is. The solution was already posted in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487136/delphi-xe2-listview-artifacts