# Count refreshes to TListView

Tags: delphi, user-interface

I've got a TListView to which I may add anything from none to several hundred items depending on the day the user has selected from the log file. I use this code to prevent unnecessary refreshes:

```
listEvents.Items.BeginUpdate();
listEvents.Items.Clear();
// Add events
listEvents.Items.EndUpdate();
```

Even so, on my fast development PC I can see a few fast flickers of the list. On the (much slower) production PCs, the flicker is noticeable and rather ugly. My question is there any way to count the number of refreshes to the TListView by hooking into an event? I could then increment a variable and display the value of the variable on a label while I debug this. I tried the TListView::OnDrawItem event but that wasn't called at all.

Comment: Set **DoubleBuffered** to `true`

Comment: DoubleBuffered is best avoided. The right solution is to use list view in virtual mode.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Why should DoubleBuffered be avoided, BTW? A quick test appears to show reduced flickering, but I'm working through it all now.

Comment: DoubleBuffered is best set to true. Listview components with the doublebuffered property set to false leave ugly artifacts even when used in virtual mode as mentioned in my earlier question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487136/delphi-xe2-listview-artifacts

Comment: @RawN: OK, followed through to that answer. Will use DoubleBuffered and try the virtual view mode. Thanks.

Comment: @RawN Hmm. You are right.

Comment: DoubleBuffered is best avoided as it involves an overhead and can also result in non-standard appearance in certain themes. More abstractly, it's usually a symptom of hiding the real problem. Generally flicker is caused by poor painting. Double buffering can paper over that, but it's usually best just to fix the painting.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I agree.

Comment: I hope in your actual code you put the calls to `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate` inside a `Try`...`Finally` block.

Comment: @Craig: Interesting comment, I'm here to learn: Why would I put Begin/EndUpdate inside a Try...Finally? I'm assuming you recommend this in case the code threw an exception when you'd end up losing updates because EndUpdate would not get called?

Comment: When you use a try block, the code in the finally part will always get executed. So by putting EndUpdate in the finally part makes sure that it gets called regardless if the try statement fails or not.

Comment: @Craig: Ok, I understand. Generally I avoid using try..catch and try..finally because of the overhead involved and the fact that faulty code can be hidden in this way. It is worthwhile to remember to use those constructs when required, though.

Comment: I tried to edit your question to show in code how it would look but the edit never came through, you can see it here though: [http://pastebin.com/hiYsrBmz](http://pastebin.com/hiYsrBmz) Aside from been a must to include try blocks, it also makes code more readible.

Comment: Finally is essential when you have an unmanaged resource. Except is what you need to avoid where you can.

Comment: Ok understood, good point. Isn't there a (small) overhead to try...finally, though? These are useful comments, though tangential to the question which is why (I think) the edit was rejected.

Comment: @Craig: I've had several perfectly reasonable edits rejected myself. Overall the reviewers have to ensure questions aren't modified to suit personal tastes. Its a delicate balance. This must be one of the reasons SO is an exceptional site. Unless unclear or incorrect, the OPs question usually deserves to be preserved more or less intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are not using the virtual listview. Use the virtual listview approach to display data. Set OwnerData property to true and handle your display in OnData event. That should prevent the flicker. Pseudo code for this would be:

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1Data(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
  Item.Caption := FloatToStr(Item.Index + 1);
  Item.SubItems.Add('Your data here');
end;
```

Comment: To use the virtual listview, do I (a) set OwnerData to True and (b) handle the OnData event? Not done this before, will give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to avoid flicker:

```
// Disable
SendMessage(listEvents.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, Integer(False), 0);
try
  listEvents.Items.BeginUpdate();
  listEvents.Items.Clear();
  // Add events
  listEvents.Items.EndUpdate();
finally
  // enable
  SendMessage(listEvents.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, Integer(True), 0);
end;
```

You may no longer be necessary to use BeginUpdate and EndUpdate.

Regards.

Comment: http://fgaillard.com/2011/02/the-unfortunate-effect-of-wm_setredraw/  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/01/24/10119211.aspx

Comment: Besides, `(Begin|End)Update()` use `WM_SETREDRAW` internally.